# Display ImageView in StickyListHeadersListView using an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am implementing the `StickyListHeadersListView` for displaying contact info. I'm using an `ArrayAdapter<Contact>`  which implements `StickyListHeadersAdapter`. Works fine and it shows an image and a string per item, the problem is that the images are being swapped around on scroll and I'm not sure why

ListView:

```
<se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
    android:id="@+id/contact_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.01"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
</se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView>


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, null, false);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.chk_selected, convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_selected));
        convertView.setTag(R.id.contact_avatar, convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_avatar));
        convertView.setTag(R.id.contact_name, convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name));
        convertView.setTag(R.id.contact_info, convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_info));
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    fill((ViewGroup) convertView, getItem(position));
        return convertView;
    }


    private void fill(ViewGroup rl, Contact contact) {  
        boolean state = itemChecked.get(contact.getId()) != null ? itemChecked.get(contact.getId()): false;
        ((CheckBox) rl.getTag(R.id.chk_selected)).setChecked(state);        
        ((CheckBox) rl.getTag(R.id.chk_selected)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new chkOnCheckedChangeListener(contact.getId()));

        if(!(contact.getFoto() == null || contact.getFoto().equals(""))) {
            fillImageView(rl, R.id.contact_avatar, contact.getFoto());
        }

        fillTextViewNombre(rl, R.id.contact_name, contact.getName());
        fillTextViewMail(rl, R.id.contact_info, contact.getInfo());
    }

    private void fillTextViewNombre(ViewGroup rl, int id, String description) {
        TextView t = ((TextView) rl.getTag(id));
        t.setText(description);
        t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
    }

    private void fillTextViewMail(ViewGroup rl, int id, String description) {
        TextView t = ((TextView) rl.getTag(id));
        t.setText(description);
        t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    }

    private static void fillImageView(ViewGroup rl, int id, String bitmap) {
    ImageView t = ((ImageView) rl.getTag(id));
    MainActivity.imageLoader.DisplayImage(bitmap, t);
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific in what you meant by "images are being swapped around on scroll" ? I have reviewed your code and it looks good but I am concerned about your if conditions.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid onscroll images change, its the thread not ending in time I ended up implementing the universal Image downloader and works fine! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the threads created by the imageLoader was out of sync with the list view when user scrolled so I ended up using the universal Image downloader and works perfect.